# How Can I merge specific rows from two datasets in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, merge, dataset

I got two different datasets.

The first one(DF1) looks like that:
ID schooltype1 date1 date2

the second one(DF2) contains
ID schooltype2 date3

Now I want to combine those rows where ID is the same and date3 is in between date1 and date2

I tried to construct a for loop

```
DF2$school3<-NA
for (i in 1:nrow(DF2)){
  if((DF1$ID==DF2$ID)&(DF2$date3>=DF1$date1)&(DF2$date3<=DF1$date2)){
    DF2$school3<-DF1$schooltype1
  }
}
```

I need a dataframe that includes
ID Schooltype1 School3 date1 date2 date3

Comment: Why not just merge by ID, then select the rows? i.e. DF3 <- merge(DF1, DF2, by = "ID");  DF3 <- with(DF3, DF3[date3 >= date1 & date3 <= date2, ])

Comment: I got several rows in DF2 that have the same ID, jsut different dates

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem.  DF3 will contain a row for each value of date3 corresponding to matching IDs.  Have you tried it?

Comment: I tried it again after deleting some NAs. Now it works, thank you very much!